# Yafaray render with hdr image as light gives black and white objects

Tags: rendering, light, external-applications

*I've created a modern interior scene with cycles and now I would like to render it with YafaRay.*

In my original scene I'm using an hdr image as environment texture for the world and as only source of light. When switching to **YafaRay** I enabled **use IBL** in world settings, but when I render not only the world image is just white (it is supposed to be a field so from the window, in the cycles render, you could see the green and the sky) but all the objects in the room are rendered in black and white and not with textures and colors.

Where am I going wrong? And which lightning method it is better to use for rendering? Also, when I try to modify the world settings, Blender starts to not responding and freezes